# Change C1-2 R1-2 into C1-C2 R1-R2 by Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I am modifying a file to conform to new standards.
I only learnt RegEx for a week many years ago but never got to use it extensively. Therefore I'm seeking a quick solution here. Any one care to help?

--Updates--
Thanks for all your reply, here are more details to the question:
The following is a snapshot of the file

```
"Qty"   "Reference" "Part Name" "PCB DECAL" "Manufacturer"  "Description"   "Value"  
"4" "C37 C67-68"    "2.2UF/10V" "C0805" ""  "Capacitor" "2.2UF/10V"  
"2" "CPL1-2"    "CPL"   "CPL-250-200-NOVIA" "Anaren"    ""  "1P510"    
"15"    "M1-15" "HOLE100"   "HOLE100_180"   ""  ""  ""  
"4" "L1-2 L5 L7"    "IND"   "L0603" ""  "MOLDED INDUCTOR, 0.5" PIN SPACING" "2.2nH"  
"9" "R2 R8 R12 R34-35"  "R" "R0603" ""  ""  "0"
```

Basically I need to detect all "-" in column 2 that are followed by a number and insert in between the letters that are at the beginning of the word.

Regarding the language, I was actually using Notepad++, thinking the same expressions could at leased by ported to other platforms such as SED if it comes to that.

Comment: Please, provide more detail. Are C and R the only possible letters? Are 1 and 2 the only possible digits and always in the same place?

Comment: Also, which language are you using the regex with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
([A-Za-z]){1,}([0-9]{1,})-([0-9]{1,})
```

The regex matches:

- The characters A to Z, a to z one or more times (first capture), followed by
- The characters 0 to 9 one or more times (second capture), followed by
- The character -, followed by
- The characters 0 to 9 one or more times (third capture)

Replacement pattern is something like this:

```
$1$2-$1$3
```

Example in PHP preg:

```
$output = preg_replace('/([A-Za-z]){1,}([0-9]{1,})-([0-9]{1,})/', '$1$2-$1$3', $input);
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you provided a more specific example, and what language/implementation you're using.

Taking your question literally, though...

```
s/(C|R)(\d)-(\d)/\1\2-\1\3/g
```

**EDIT:**

In light of the comments, you want to replace

```
\b(C|R)(\d+)-(\d+)
```

with

```
\1\2-\1\3
```

Comment: If you really wanted to go literal, `s/C1-2 R1-2/C1-C2 R1-R2/g` :)

Comment: See edit for updated solution, which, admittedly was given by others, but this is a trivial problem anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to do something like this (Python example):

```
>>> import re
>>> test = 'C1-2 R1-2' 
>>> re.sub(r'([A-Z])(\d+)-(\d+)', r'\1\2-\1\3', test)
'C1-C2 R1-R2'
```

Basically, you need to replace `([A-Z])(\d+)-(\d+)` with `\1\2-\1\3`.